# Use a gif as a placeholder while downloading an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, gif, activity-indicator

My problem is that I want to show a gif in the UIImageView while downloading a picture from remote server. After I downloaded the picture from remote server, I want this downloaded picture to be shown on the screen.

Without problem, I achieved showing the downloaded picture on the screen, which is not difficult of course. However, I could not achieve displaying a custom preinstalled gif in my local while trying to download that picture. Default ActivityIndicator icon appears while downloading.

I did try a few things but I still could not make it. Is there any suggestion for that ?

I put some pictures:

[image]

Before I began to download: UImageView with white background color

[image]

After I started to download image for UImageView: default activity indicator

[image]

Downloaded image: Which I wanted so.
I just want to replace second picture: Activity indicator with my gif. I hope I am understood.

Comment: if you show what you tried it would help us help you.

Comment: Are you able to show the code that you have tried? so we can try and help

Comment: check out this library to use gif in imageview
https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Answer (score 2):

You cannot play a gif format file in a `UIImageView`. If you have an array of images, you can ainmate them in the `imageView` and it will be just like a gif.You can also repeat the animation if you want to.

You need to add `UIImage+animatedGIF` category to support gif in `imageView`.

If you want to play gifs from the url, you can consider the `webView` instead of `imageView`.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of default activity indicator? At least I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for animated GIFs in iOS. I found a third-party framework that lets you display animated GIFs. I'm not at my Mac right now so I don't have the info, but it looks like there are quite a few libraries that offer animated GIF support on Github.

As Mr. T. says you can also use an array of images in UIImageView to get the same effect. (And there are tools that let you decompose an animated GIF into its frames.)